# dos partition table confuses gparted

Tags: partitioning, gparted

The partition table on one of my disks is unreadable by gparted.   Here is the output of fdisk

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000aa587

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048   3074047   3072000   1.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         3074048 257759231 254685184 121.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3  *    257759232 360159622 102400391  48.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda4       360161279 976773119 616611841   294G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5       360161280 397024561  36863282  17.6G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       397027328 399075327   2048000  1000M 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       399077376 401121279   2043904   998M 83 Linux
/dev/sda8       401123328 976773119 575649792 274.5G 83 Linux
```

fixparts found no problems.   Here's the table it sees:

```
Disk size is 976773168 sectors (465.8 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x000AA587
MBR partitions:

                           Can Be   Can Be
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status   Logical  Primary   Code
   1                  2048      3074047   primary              Y      0x07
   2               3074048    257759231   primary              Y      0x07
   3      *      257759232    360159622   primary              Y      0x83
   5             360161280    397024561   logical     Y               0x83
   6             397027328    399075327   logical     Y               0x83
   7             399077376    401121279   logical     Y               0x83
   8             401123328    976773119   logical     Y               0x83
```

parted -ls give:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1574MB  1573MB  primary   ntfs
 2      1574MB  132GB   130GB   primary   ntfs
 3      132GB   184GB   52.4GB  primary   ext4         boot
 4      184GB   500GB   316GB   extended               lba
 5      184GB   203GB   18.9GB  logical   ext4
 6      203GB   204GB   1049MB  logical   zfs
 7      204GB   205GB   1046MB  logical   zfs
 8      205GB   500GB   295GB   logical   zfs
```

I caused the problem some time ago by using gparted to wipe and create a new partition.    Everything works but I'm worried that something is clearly slightly off with the table.  That might cause problems when I upgrade the system to 18.04.

I am running Ubuntu 17.10, Linux w540 4.13.0-39-generic.  gparted is 0.28.1-0ubuntu1

Help?  Thanks.

gparted gives no errors, but says

```
Partition table: none
Heads: 255
Sectors/track: 63
Cylinders: 60801
Total sectors: 976773168
Sector size: 512
```

and

```
/dev/sda zfs jun16 465.76GiB --- ---
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to add the output of `sudo parted -ls` which might add some information because `parted` is related to `gparted`.

Comment: What happens when you try and use `gparted` to read it?  Does it give a specific error message?